# Construct a dictionary from a list of dictionary keys, sub-keys and values

Tags: python

Have a list of dictionaries:

```
list_dict = [['key1', {'subkey1': 0}],
             ['key1', {'subkey2': 2}],
             ['key1', {'subkey5': 5}],
             ['key2', {'subkey2': 4}],
             ['key2', {'subkey1': 8}],
             ['key1', {'sybkey5': 10}]]
```

How can `list_dict` be converted to a neat dictionary as follows?

```
{'key1': {'subkey1': 0, 'subkey2': 2, 'subkey5': 5},
 'key2': {'subkey2': 4, 'subkey1': 8, 'sybkey5': 10}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
d = dict()
for item in list_dict:
    d.setdefault(item[0], {}).update(item[1])
```

From the [Python 3 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

> setdefault(key[, default])
>
> If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of default and return default. default defaults to None.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict


list_dict = [['key1', {'subkey1': 0}],
             ['key1', {'subkey2': 2}],
             ['key1', {'subkey5': 5}],
             ['key2', {'subkey2': 4}],
             ['key2', {'subkey1': 8}],
             ['key1', {'sybkey5': 10}]]

d = defaultdict(dict)

for k, v in list_dict:
    d[k].update(v)
d
```

output:

```
defaultdict(dict,
            {'key1': {'subkey1': 0, 'subkey2': 2, 'subkey5': 5, 'sybkey5': 10},
             'key2': {'subkey2': 4, 'subkey1': 8}})
```

---

or you can use `dict.setdefault` which is a bit slower :

```
d = {}
for k, v in list_dict:
    d.setdefault(k, {}).update(v)
```

output:

```
{'key1': {'subkey1': 0, 'subkey2': 2, 'subkey5': 5, 'sybkey5': 10},
 'key2': {'subkey2': 4, 'subkey1': 8}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> result = defaultdict(dict)
>>> for item in list_dict :
...     result[item[0]].update(item[1])
... 
>>> result
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'key2': {'subkey2': 4, 'subkey1': 8}, 'key1': {'subkey5': 5, 'subkey2': 2, 'sybkey5': 10, 'subkey1': 0}})
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

conventional approach

```
new_dict = {}
for i in list_dict:
    if i[0] in new_dict.keys():
            new_dict[i[0]].update(i[1])
    else:
            new_dict[i[0]]=i[1]
```